# libcef.dll.pdb CEF3 file, check for insufficient disk space, invalid path, or insufficient privilege

Tags: windows, dll, chromium-embedded, pdb-files

During the compilation (cmd- ninja -C out/Debug cefclient) of CEF3 with windows 7, getting below error.
I have set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0 suggested by many blogs but getting same error again & again.

Error: error LNK1201: error writing to program database 'Chromium\src\out\Debug\libcef.dll.pdb'; check for insufficient disk space, invalid path, or insufficient privilege.
size of libcef.dll.pdb is going more than 1 GB.

OS- 64 bit, Windows 7
RAM - 8 GB
Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0 (vs2013 version 12.0.31101.00 updated 4)

Please suggest the solution?

Comment: While waiting for a fix, you can disable PDB creation and download it from [here](http://www.magpcss.net/cef_downloads/)

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is an error from linker.
Unless you really exhausted disk space (it happened to me twice, so don't rule it out), requirements are ok (Win7 x64, depot tools toolchain to 0, VS 2013 update 4). RAM sounds a little low, but not a stopper. Recheck if you configured a 32-bit build (target_arch on GYP_DEFINES) and not a 64-bit one.
Retry by manually deleting the .pdb file and rerun *ninja -C out\Debug cefclient*.